# Access builtin functions by __builtins__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script:

*a.py*

```
print(__builtins__.max)
import b
```

and the following module:

*b.py*

```
print(__builtins__.max)
```

Launching them with `python3 a.py` I get:

```
<built-in function max>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import b
  File "/home/antonio/Scrivania/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(__builtins__.max)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'max'
```

so I don't understand. Why in the script `__builtins__` is assigned to the builtins module instead in the module `__builtins__` is assigned to a dict?

Comment: @martineau: no, `__builtins__` is a global global. It is how built-in objects are resolved everywhere. But it is an implementation detail, and a module in one location, a dictionary in all others.

Comment: Looks like Python devs didn't think about this properly. I was going to use `__builtins__` to access `ImportError` universally in Python 2.x and 3.x in a module that unfortunately has its own `ImportError` as part of the public API. Looks like it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `__builtins__`; use the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) instead.

The `__builtins__` object is an implementation detail you should not rely on. From the `builtins` module documentation:

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. **The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute**. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Note my emphasis there; you can either have a dictionary or the module object when you access `__builtins__`.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know. But it's pretty odd what I noticed, don't you think so?

Comment: @antox: why is it odd you noticed? The documentation clearly states it is one or the other. The module is imported once (into `__main__` IIRC) and from there on out all other modules get the `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: Now that I have read the doumentation it's not even odd, my fault.

Comment: P.S. what does IIRC mean?

Comment: @antox: *If I Recall Correctly*. E.g. I did not verify my statement, it came from memory only.

Comment: @Martijn: So why wasn't `__builtins__` also in module b's globals (since it's being run with the same implementation as module a)?

Comment: @martineau: it is there. It is a dictionary, not a module object. Which is why you get an `AttributeError`, not a `NameError`; `__builtins__` is a dictionary and `__builtins__.max` is not an attribute on that dictionary. `__builtins__['max']` would work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can I still make a question? Why doesn't `__builtins__` in the b module point to a dict? couldn't it point to the builtin module too? what's the advantage in doing so?

Comment: @antox: I haven't yet fully traced all uses of bulitins in the C code, so at the moment I don't know why. I do see that frames have a `f_builtins` entry that is always a dictionary reference. So if frames have a direct reference, then the entry in `__builtins__` is probably just informative or a cache.

Comment: @antox: if so it was probably just simpler in the initial setup to stuff in the module, and in later cases copy the frame reference over. The reason then would be pragmatism.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's still preatty confusing to me, maybe it's a too advanced topic for now, I can't see the benefits in having directly access to `__builtins__.__dict__`

Comment: is the purpose of `__builtins__` to keep a reference to the builtin scope? because I noticed that assigning something to `__builtins__` breaks everything, so it's still pretty confusing

Comment: @antox: however interesting this is, I just don't have the time right now to trace through the codebase for how `__builtins__` is used. I do know that name lookups don't look at `globals()['__builtins__']` at all when resolving a `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode; it looks at the reference on the frame object.

Comment: I have to downvote, sorry. – “ImportError: No module named builtins” – Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @Pavel: that's because this is a question about Python **3**. A lot of modules were renamed. In Python 2 it is named [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) instead. Please do *ask* next time before voting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough. Aside from the voting issue, `__builtins__` seems to be available in latest Python 2.x versions as well, but the “implementation detail” problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? I can't imagine what they were thinking when they made `__builtins__` mean different things in a script and in a module. I was using `__builtins__` to access built-in `ImportError` from a library that defines its own `ImportError` as a public API and it worked for me until today.

I do not know the exact difference. My `__builtins__.ImportError` was working in a module for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x. Now with some upstream changes in the code the same construct fails exactly like in your case. I found your question using web search and I'm going to answer for others who might get into the same situations.

You cannot use `__builtins__` due to the above problem and you cannot use `builtins` in Python 2.x, but I managed to fix that using the *six* python module.

```
from six.moves import builtins
```

This works for me both in Python 2.x and in Python 3.x and it works in the exact same place where `__builtins__` fails. Hope that helps.