# The Python console and text editor output different output for __builtins__

Tags: python, blender

I'm scripting using Python in Blender, a 3D graphics tool. I initially intended to post this topic on the blender stack exchange, but I've come to the conclusion that it's closer to the basics of Python, which led me to write the question here. Please let me know if I'm on the wrong forum!

I made the mistake of using the default function name as a variable name in Python some time ago, like `list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. To take the more extreme case, all the print functions in my code would not have worked if I had declared a variable like `print = 'a'`.

---

So I tried to write a code that prints out all the variable names that are already reserved. Even if I wanted to use `list` or `print` as the variable names, I would use a different name because I saw `True` returned and knew that this was already using these names in `__builtins__`. Now that I've tested it in the Python console, I went to a text editor and ran the same code, but this time I got `False` instead of `True`. What happened?

[image: keyword in dir(builtins) in console]

[image: keyword in dir(builtins) in text editor]

---

I used the `dir()` function to check the values actually inside `__builtins__`. The output from the Python console contained `print` and `list` in `__builtins__` as expected, but the output from the text editor had different values. Upon closer inspection, I noticed that there were values such as `keys`, `items`, `values`, which are methods available on the dictionary!

[image: dir(builtins) in console]

[image: dir(builtins) in text editor]

---

This time, I used the `type()` function to print the type of `__builtins__`. The Python console printed `<class 'module'>` and the text editor printed `<class 'dict'>`.

[image: type(builtins) in console]

[image: type(builtins) in text editor]

---

I know that Blender's python console and text editor work separately within different scopes, but I don't know what's going on specifically. Why is the output different for `__builtins__`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050317/2285236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different implementations of Python, and the value of `__builtins__` is deliberately left underspecified in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

So `__builtins__` is simply a convenience mechanism for particular implementations and is generally set to either `builtins` or `builtins.__dict__`. It looks like your Python console does the former and Blender's version does the latter. To do it in a uniform way across implementations, you can do

```
import builtins
print(type(builtins)) # <class 'module'>
print(type(builtins.__dict__)) # <class 'dict'>
```